# French Server and HTTP Requests

Tags: httprequest

I created an application and I have only french users submissions with an SQL server (OVH). No US, UK ... users ! I can see on my Statistic page some foreign downloaders though. Is there any restrictions for people outside my country (I use AsynkTasks, HTTP Requests and SQL server) !
Thank You So Much For Your Answer !
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I just read what "AsynkTasks" is, and I assumed you're working on android, which I know nothing about. I don't know if (or how) this might help you, but if your app can somehow send a request to somewhere that can run this PHP:

http://chir.ag/projects/geoiploc/

It returns the geographical location by requester IP. Hope this helps.